# Oddities when using joda to format certain time spans

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I'm having hard time understanding what's going on here ... I'm trying to convert a time span to a string (i.e. "2 years, 6 days, 4 hours, 23 seconds").

A sample of the numbers I'm getting is the following:

> Start: 1309605480723      End: 1341227880000
>   Start: Jul 2, 2011 4:18:00 AM
>   End: Jul 2, 2012 4:18:00 AM
>   span.toString: PT8783H59M59.277S
>   formatter.print(span): 0 years, 0 months, 1 days, 23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds
>   span.toString(formatter): 0 years, 0 months, 1 days, 23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds

The code that's producing the above is:

```
Period span = new Period(mEndTime - mStartTime);
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .printZeroAlways()
    .appendYears().appendSuffix(" year", " years").appendSeparator(", ")
    .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" month", " months").appendSeparator(", ")
    .appendDays().appendSuffix(" day", " days").appendSeparator(", ")
    .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hour", " hours").appendSeparator(", ")
    .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minute", " minutes").appendSeparator(", ")
    .appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" second", " seconds")
    .toFormatter();
Log.d(LOGTAG, "formatter.print: " + formatter.print(span.normalizedStandard()));
Log.d(LOGTAG, "span.toString: " + span.normalizedStandard().toString(formatter));
```

Can anyone explain these numbers?
Maybe I'm doing something stupid and can't see it (it's 4am afterall), but I just can't see why these 8783 hours can't even be up-converted to a few days?

Thanks.

Comment: The logs you're getting don't match what the code is supposed to print: it's supposed to print "formatter.print: ", and it prints "formatter.print(span)". Are you sure you're looking at the right logs (or running the right code)?

Comment: Copy +  Paste ... The logs & code are trimmed to show only what is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation to the rescue! :)

org.joda.time.Period.Period(long duration)

Creates a period from the given millisecond duration using the standard set of fields.

Only precise fields in the period type will be used. For the standard period type this is the time fields only. Thus the **year, month, week and day fields will not be populated**.

try:

```
Period span = new Period(mStartTime, mEndTime);
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but the constructor you suggest to use also uses the stabdard set of fields. You should add a third argument: PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime()

Comment: It worked when I cut and pasted my solution. Yes, many of the constructors indeed use the standard fine-grained fields, but I think Period(long,long) will always work. I used jodatime version 1.6.2, but jmmv.

Comment: It's stange, because the javadoc for this constructor says: "Creates a period from the given interval endpoints using the standard set of fields. "

Comment: This worked: Period span = new Period(mStartTime, mEndTime);

This also worked: Period span = new Period(mStartTime, mEndTime, PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());

Thanks